Book size 6 X 9
I am having a problem with book format when converting to a PDF. The layout page size is 6 X 9 which was selected at start but when convert to PDF, it shows as 8.5 X 11. Can anyone assist? I am using Microsoft WORD current version, 2024.

You should ask this in a forum dedicated to Microsoft Word. You'll get better and quicker help there.
